# Unwanted empty page in the middle of a chapter

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, titles, blank-page

I am having an empty page in the middle of a chapter of my document. The only information that appears is the page number. The pages before and after are filled with text and figures.

I have checked all float placement specifiers and still cannot find the reason for this behaviour.

Any suggestion where to seek for a solution will be appreciated.

Edit:

I managed to find out what causes this problem.

I am using tikz and pstricks at the same time. If the commands `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\maketitle`, and `\tableofcontents` are enabled at the beginning of the document, the pspicture is not displayed in the document and an empty page appears instead.
I compile using `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`

Here is the version information:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

On another machine with another latex version, this is compiling without any issues.
Here is a short example of the code I would like compile:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pst-all}   %%% needed to display labels on axes correctly
\usepackage{subcaption}



%%% to disable the ps-grid:
%\let\psgrid\relax    %%% not workin well
\makeatletter       %%% better use these three lines to make grid disappear
\def\psgrid@iv(#1)(#2)(#3){}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\title{No title}
\author{The Author}

%\maketitle  %%% causes error

%\tableofcontents  %%% causes error

\chapter{chapter one}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(6, 6)
        \psgrid
        \FPset\anglealpha{70}
        \FPeval\anglealphaplus{anglealpha + 90.}
        \FPeval\anglealphahalf{anglealpha * 0.5}
        \FPeval\anglealphahalfplus{anglealphahalf + 90.}
        \FPset\unitvec{2}
        \FPeval\pbegin{1.5 * unitvec}
        \FPeval\pend{pbegin + unitvec}
        \def\pointdummy{none}
        \def\namedummy{none}%{default}


        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=135, PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](0, 0){O}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=45, PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](1; \anglealpha){I}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=180, PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](1; \anglealphaplus){J}
        \pstOIJGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](\unitvec,0){I'}{O}{I}{J}(0,\unitvec){J'}(-2, 0){I''}(5, 0){I'''}(\pbegin, 0){I4'}(\pend, 0){I5'}(-1.5, -0.5){I6'}(-1.5, 0.5){I7'}(3.5, 0.5){I8'}(4.5, 0.5){I9'}(4, 0.5){I10'}(6.5, 0){I11'}
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt, linecolor=cyan]{->}(O)(I')
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt, linecolor=cyan]{->}(O)(J')


        \pstGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](1; 0){X}
        \pstGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](1; 90){Y}
        \pstOIJGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](\unitvec, 0){XX}{O}{X}{Y}(0, \unitvec){YY}(-5, 0){XXX}(6, 0){XXXX}(\pbegin, 0){X5X}(\pend, 0){X6X}(-3, 0.5){X7X}(-3, -0.5){X8X}(3.5, -0.5){X9X}(4.5, -0.5){X10X}(4, -.5){X11X}
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(O)(XX)
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(O)(YY)

        \pstGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](1; \anglealphahalf){X''}
        \pstGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](1; \anglealphahalfplus){Y''}
        \pstOIJGeonode[PointSymbol = \pointdummy, PointName = \namedummy](\unitvec, 0){XX''}{O}{X''}{Y''}(0, \unitvec){YY''}
        \psline[linecolor = orange]{->}(O)(XX'')
        \psline[linecolor = orange]{->}(O)(YY'')

        \psline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth = 0.3pt](XXX)(XXXX)
        \psline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth = 0.3pt](I'')(I11')

        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(I4')(I5')
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(X5X)(X6X)

        \psline{|-|}(I6')(I7')
        \psline{|-|}(X8X)(X7X)
        \psline{|-|}(X9X)(X10X)
        \psline{|-|}(I8')(I9')

        \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius = 3.7, LabelSep = 4.0]{XXXX}{O}{I5'}{$\alpha$}
        \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius = 1.8, LabelSep = 2.1]{XXXX}{O}{XX''}{$\frac{\alpha}{2}$}

        \uput[20](I'){$\hatvec{e}_{1'}$}
        \uput[\anglealphaplus](J'){$\hatvec{e}_{2'}$}
        \uput[-90](XX){$\hatvec{e}_1$}
        \uput[90](YY){$\hatvec{e}_2$}
        \uput[\anglealphahalf](XX''){$\hatvec{e}_{1''}$}
        \uput[\anglealphahalfplus](YY''){$\hatvec{e}_{2''}$}
        \uput[90](X6X){$\hatvec{p}_1$}
        \uput[0](I5'){$\hatvec{p}_2$}
        \uput[45](X8X){$\sigma_1$}
        \uput[115](I6'){$\sigma_2$}
        \uput[\anglealphaplus](I10'){$\sigma(\kappa_2)$}
        \uput[-90](X11X){$\sigma(\kappa_1)$}
    \end{pspicture}
\caption{Caption 1.}
\end{figure}


\chapter{chapter two}


% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width = 3cm]
\tikzstyle{redblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=2.cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width = 2cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{python} = [rectangle, draw, fill = green!20, text width=1.8cm, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=2pt]
\tikzstyle{interaction} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=-70, text width = 4.cm, text badly centered, draw, fill = pink!20]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
            \node [redblock, fill=red!20] (start) {start};
            \node [interaction, right of = start, node distance = 3.8cm] (files) {A};
            \node [python, right of = files, node distance = 5.5cm] (analyse) {B};
            \node [interaction, below of = files, node distance = 1.5cm] (images) {C};
            \node [python, right of = images, node distance = 3.9cm] (reconstruct) {D};
            \node [block, below of = images, node distance = 1.5cm] (display) {E};
            \node [python, below of = reconstruct, node distance = 2.7cm] (rec_marker) {F};
            \node [python, below of = rec_marker, node distance = 2cm] (calc_gonio) {G};
            \node [decision, below of = display, node distance = 3.2cm] (ports_ok) {H};
            \node [block, below of = ports_ok, node distance = 2.4cm] (port_n) {I};
            \node [decision, below of = port_n, node distance = 2cm] (overlay_ok) {J};
            \node [python, right of = overlay_ok, node distance = 4.1cm] (overlay) {K};
            \node [redblock, fill=red!20, left of = overlay_ok, node distance = 3.8cm] (cancel) {L};
            \node [block, below of = overlay_ok, node distance = 1.8cm] (irrad) {M};
            \node [decision, below of = irrad, node distance = 1.7cm] (last_port) {N};
            \node [redblock,fill=red!20, left of = last_port, node distance = 3.8cm] (end) {end};

            \node [block, fill=blue!8, draw opacity = 0.6, text opacity = 0.6, below of = last_port, node distance = 1.8cm] (GUI) {O};
            \node [python, fill=green!8, draw opacity = 0.6, text opacity = 0.6, minimum width = 3.5cm, right of = GUI, node distance = 4.7cm] (asdf) {P};


            \path [line] (start) -- (files);
            \path [line, style = dashed] (files) -- (analyse);
            \path [line] (files) -- (images);
            \path [line] (images) -- (reconstruct);
            \path [line] (reconstruct) |- (display);
            \path [line] (display) |- (rec_marker);
            \path [line] (rec_marker) -- (calc_gonio);
            \path [line, style = dashed] ([xshift = -.3cm] analyse.south) |- (calc_gonio);
            \path [line] (calc_gonio) -- (ports_ok);
            \path [line] (ports_ok) -- node [near start] {yes} (port_n);
            \path [line] (ports_ok) -| node [near start] {no} ([xshift = -1cm] display.west)
            |- (display);
            \path [line] ([xshift = -1cm] display.west) |- node [near start] {or} (images);
            \path [line] ([yshift = - 0.3cm] port_n.east) -| (overlay);
            \path [line] (overlay) -- (overlay_ok);
            \path [line] (overlay_ok) -- node [near start] {yes} (irrad);
            \path [line] (overlay_ok) -- node [near start] {no} (cancel);
            \path [line] (irrad) -- (last_port);
            \path [line] (last_port) -- node [near start] {yes} (end);
            \path [line] (last_port) -| node [near start] {no} node [near end] {} ([xshift = 3.3cm, yshift = 0.3cm] port_n.east) -- ([yshift = 0.3cm] port_n.east);
            \path [line, style = dashed] ([xshift = .3cm] analyse.south) |- (overlay);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption 2.}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: have you use `[H]` float placemen or do you get a warning from latex about a float being too big.  You really need to make as small example document that demonstrates the problem. or have you used a command that internally uses `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: Details of the kind of document David Carlisle mentions are explained in [these instructions for creating a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Works with `pdflatex --shell-escape` or `xelatex` which doesn't need the whole `auto-pst-pdf` and `\ifpdf ... \fi` stuff. However, I changed your PSTricks code to make it easier to read. By the way the macro `\hatvec` wasn't defined:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
  % Define block styles
  \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width = 3cm]
  \tikzstyle{redblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=2.cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=.5cm, minimum width = 2cm]
  \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
  \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
  \tikzstyle{python} = [rectangle, draw, fill = green!20, text width=1.8cm, text badly centered, 
     node distance=3cm, inner sep=2pt]
  \tikzstyle{interaction} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=-70, text   
     width = 4.cm, text badly centered, draw, fill = pink!20]
\else
  \usepackage{pst-eucl}
\fi
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\hatvec\vec

\begin{document}
\title{No title}
\author{The Author}

\maketitle  
\tableofcontents 

\chapter{chapter one}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(6, 6)
%        \psgrid
        \def\anglealpha{70 }
        \def\anglealphaplus{\anglealpha  90 add }
        \def\anglealphahalf{\anglealpha 0.5 mul }
        \def\anglealphahalfplus{\anglealphahalf 90 add }
        \def\unitvec{2 }
        \def\pbegin{1.5  \unitvec mul }
        \def\pend{\pbegin \unitvec add }
        \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=135](0, 0){O}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=45](1; \anglealpha){I}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=180](!1 \anglealphaplus PtoC){J}
        \pstOIJGeonode(!\unitvec 0){I'}{O}{I}{J}(!0 \unitvec){J'}%
                      (-2, 0){I''}(5, 0){I'''}%
                      (!\pbegin 0){I4'}(!\pend  0){I5'}%
                      (-1.5, -0.5){I6'}(-1.5, 0.5){I7'}%
                      (3.5, 0.5){I8'}(4.5, 0.5){I9'}%
                      (4, 0.5){I10'}(6.5, 0){I11'}
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt, linecolor=cyan]{->}(O)(I')
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt, linecolor=cyan]{->}(O)(J')
        \pstGeonode(1; 0){X} \pstGeonode(1; 90){Y}
        \pstOIJGeonode(\unitvec, 0){XX}{O}{X}{Y}%
                      (0, \unitvec){YY}(-5, 0){XXX}%
                      (6, 0){XXXX}(!\pbegin 0){X5X}%
                      (!\pend 0){X6X}(-3, 0.5){X7X}%
                      (-3, -0.5){X8X}(3.5, -0.5){X9X}%
                      (4.5, -0.5){X10X}(4, -.5){X11X}
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(O)(XX)
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(O)(YY)
        \pstGeonode(!1 \anglealphahalf PtoC ){X''}
        \pstGeonode(!1 \anglealphahalfplus PtoC ){Y''}
        \pstOIJGeonode(\unitvec, 0){XX''}{O}{X''}{Y''}(0, \unitvec){YY''}
        \psline[linecolor = orange]{->}(O)(XX'')
        \psline[linecolor = orange]{->}(O)(YY'')
        \psline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth = 0.3pt](XXX)(XXXX)
        \psline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth = 0.3pt](I'')(I11')
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(I4')(I5')
        \psline[linewidth = 1pt]{->}(X5X)(X6X)
        \psline{|-|}(I6')(I7')
        \psline{|-|}(X8X)(X7X)
        \psline{|-|}(X9X)(X10X)
        \psline{|-|}(I8')(I9')
        \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius = 3.7, LabelSep = 4.0]{XXXX}{O}{I5'}{$\alpha$}
        \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius = 1.8, LabelSep = 2.1]{XXXX}{O}{XX''}{$\frac{\alpha}{2}$}
        \uput[20](I'){$\hatvec{e}_{1'}$}
        \uput[!\anglealphaplus](J'){$\hatvec{e}_{2'}$}
        \uput[-90](XX){$\hat{\vec{e}_1}$}
        \uput[90](YY){$\hat{\vec{e}_2}$}
        \uput[!\anglealphahalf](XX''){$\hatvec{e}_{1''}$}
        \uput[!\anglealphahalfplus](YY''){$\hatvec{e}_{2''}$}
        \uput[90](X6X){$\hatvec{p}_1$}
        \uput[0](I5'){$\hatvec{p}_2$}
        \uput[45](X8X){$\sigma_1$}
        \uput[115](I6'){$\sigma_2$}
        \uput[!\anglealphaplus](I10'){$\sigma(\kappa_2)$}
        \uput[-90](X11X){$\sigma(\kappa_1)$}
    \end{pspicture}
\caption{Caption 1.}
\end{figure}


\chapter{chapter two}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \ifpdf
    \resizebox{0.6\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
            \node [redblock, fill=red!20] (start) {start};
            \node [interaction, right of = start, node distance = 3.8cm] (files) {A};
            \node [python, right of = files, node distance = 5.5cm] (analyse) {B};
            \node [interaction, below of = files, node distance = 1.5cm] (images) {C};
            \node [python, right of = images, node distance = 3.9cm] (reconstruct) {D};
            \node [block, below of = images, node distance = 1.5cm] (display) {E};
            \node [python, below of = reconstruct, node distance = 2.7cm] (rec_marker) {F};
            \node [python, below of = rec_marker, node distance = 2cm] (calc_gonio) {G};
            \node [decision, below of = display, node distance = 3.2cm] (ports_ok) {H};
            \node [block, below of = ports_ok, node distance = 2.4cm] (port_n) {I};
            \node [decision, below of = port_n, node distance = 2cm] (overlay_ok) {J};
            \node [python, right of = overlay_ok, node distance = 4.1cm] (overlay) {K};
            \node [redblock, fill=red!20, left of = overlay_ok, node distance = 3.8cm] (cancel) {L};
            \node [block, below of = overlay_ok, node distance = 1.8cm] (irrad) {M};
            \node [decision, below of = irrad, node distance = 1.7cm] (last_port) {N};
            \node [redblock,fill=red!20, left of = last_port, node distance = 3.8cm] (end) {end};

            \node [block, fill=blue!8, draw opacity = 0.6, text opacity = 0.6, below of = last_port, node distance = 1.8cm] (GUI) {O};
            \node [python, fill=green!8, draw opacity = 0.6, text opacity = 0.6, minimum width = 3.5cm, right of = GUI, node distance = 4.7cm] (asdf) {P};


            \path [line] (start) -- (files);
            \path [line, style = dashed] (files) -- (analyse);
            \path [line] (files) -- (images);
            \path [line] (images) -- (reconstruct);
            \path [line] (reconstruct) |- (display);
            \path [line] (display) |- (rec_marker);
            \path [line] (rec_marker) -- (calc_gonio);
            \path [line, style = dashed] ([xshift = -.3cm] analyse.south) |- (calc_gonio);
            \path [line] (calc_gonio) -- (ports_ok);
            \path [line] (ports_ok) -- node [near start] {yes} (port_n);
            \path [line] (ports_ok) -| node [near start] {no} ([xshift = -1cm] display.west)
            |- (display);
            \path [line] ([xshift = -1cm] display.west) |- node [near start] {or} (images);
            \path [line] ([yshift = - 0.3cm] port_n.east) -| (overlay);
            \path [line] (overlay) -- (overlay_ok);
            \path [line] (overlay_ok) -- node [near start] {yes} (irrad);
            \path [line] (overlay_ok) -- node [near start] {no} (cancel);
            \path [line] (irrad) -- (last_port);
            \path [line] (last_port) -- node [near start] {yes} (end);
            \path [line] (last_port) -| node [near start] {no} node [near end] {} ([xshift = 3.3cm, yshift = 0.3cm] port_n.east) -- ([yshift = 0.3cm] port_n.east);
            \path [line, style = dashed] ([xshift = .3cm] analyse.south) |- (overlay);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \fi
    \caption{caption 2.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can simplify your PSTricks image with `\pcline`. Then you can use the `\nXput` macros:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
        \def\anglealpha{70 }
        \def\anglealphaplus{\anglealpha  90 add }
        \def\anglealphahalf{\anglealpha 0.5 mul }
        \def\anglealphahalfplus{\anglealphahalf 90 add }
        \def\unitvec{2 }
        \def\pbegin{1.5  \unitvec mul }
        \def\pend{\pbegin \unitvec add }

    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,-2)(6, 6)
        \def\anglealpha{70 }
        \def\anglealphaplus{\anglealpha  90 add }
        \def\anglealphahalf{\anglealpha 0.5 mul }
        \def\anglealphahalfplus{\anglealphahalf 90 add }
        \def\unitvec{2 }
        \def\pbegin{1.5  \unitvec mul }
        \def\pend{\pbegin \unitvec add }
        \psset{linewidth=1pt,arrows=->}
        \pcline[linecolor=cyan](0,0)(2;\anglealpha)
        \pcline[linecolor=cyan](0,0)(!2 \anglealphaplus PtoC)
        \pcline(0,0)(2;90)\ncput[npos=1.2]{$\vec{e_2}$}
        \pcline(0,0)(2;0)\nbput[npos=1]{$\vec{e_1}$}
        \pcline[linecolor=orange](0,0)(!2 \anglealphahalfplus PtoC)\ncput[npos=1.2]{$\vec{e_{2''}}$}
        \pcline[linecolor=orange](0,0)(!2 \anglealphahalf PtoC)\ncput[npos=1.2]{$\vec{e_{1''}}$}
        \psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.3pt]{-}(-5,0)(6,0)
        \psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.3pt]{-}(!2 \anglealpha 180 add PtoC)(6;\anglealpha)
        \psline(!\pbegin 0)(!\pend 0)
        \psline(!\pbegin \anglealpha PtoC)(!\pend \anglealpha PtoC)
        \pcline{|-|}(-3,0.5)(-3,-0.5)\naput[npos=0.8]{$\sigma_1$}
        \rput{!\anglealpha 180 add}{\pcline{|-|}(1.5,0.5)(1.5,-0.5)\nbput[npos=0.2,nrot=:D]{$\sigma_2$}}
        \pcline[offset=-0.5]{|-|}(3.5,0)(4.5,0)\nbput{$\sigma(\kappa_1)$}
        \pcline[offset=0.5]{|-|}(3.5;\anglealpha)(4.5;\anglealpha)\naput{$\sigma(\kappa_2)$}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]